# How can I create a Hadoop cluster with different OS?

Tags: linux, macos, hadoop

I installed Hadoop 2.7.1 on my 3 computers, 1 64-bit mac and 2 32-bit linux machines, in my home network. I have already successfully configured them to run on the single node mode and set up the SSH authorized keys. I want to use my mac as the master and the linux as the slaves. When I run the start scripts on mac I get errors like

```
hadoop@10.0.1.100: bash: line 0: cd: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec: No such file or directory
```

10.0.1.100 is the ip of one of my linux machines and /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec is the $HADOOP_PREFIX on my mac. so is possible to construct a Hadoop cluster containing different operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly provide the following hdfs-site.xml core-site,slave file,master file on master server. Also the environment variables. If all is configure it should be a minimal config like adding the slave host ip or hostnames in slave file of master server and a few more make